# How to allow only double numbers in input React js

Tags: reactjs

Currently, i'm using this reg exp:

`!/[0-9]/`

But for digits like '0.40', or '2.43' this doesn't work. How can I change that reg exp above to match floats as well?

Answer (score 1):

please try this:

```
/(\-?\d*\.?\d+)/
```

- '-?' - optional negative sign
- '\d*' - 0 or more digits
- '.?'  - optional dot
- '\d+' - one or more digits